# UIView animation causes a UIButton to jump

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

UI is programmatically generated in my app.  I have few `buttons` and `texboxes` in the UI. I have developed a custom `uidatapicker` object, which pops up from the top and animates to the middle of the screen. When `uidatapicker` pops up I draw another `UIView`(called helper view) with the size of the screen so all other `uiobject`s in the screen except `uidatepicker` become disabled. 
But when the `UIDatePicker` is animating a button in the UI jumps to another location. Also I have three buttons in my UI. It happens with only one button(one UIButon in the UIView). Other two buttons are ok. Also there is no significant difference between those buttons except the button text.

- I removed the earlier described view(helper view), but still the
  problem is occurring.
- I need to know why this is occurring how to
  prevent it.
- Also I have lot of other pages which works fine.

The code

```
-(void)openEditDateTime:(UIDatePickerMode) mode {
    if ([clientView viewWithTag:9]) {
        [self cancelPressed];
    }
    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake((clientView.frame.size.width/2)-160, (clientView.frame.size.height/2)+91, 320, 44);
    CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake((clientView.frame.size.width/2)-160, (clientView.frame.size.height/2)-125, 320, 216);

    backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:clientView.bounds];
    backgroundView.alpha = 0;
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    backgroundView.tag = 9;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPressed:)];
    [backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [clientView addSubview:backgroundView];
    [self bringToFront:backgroundView];

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)];
    datePicker.tag = 10;
    datePicker.datePickerMode = mode;
    [clientView addSubview:datePicker];
    [clientView bringSubviewToFront:datePicker];
    [datePicker becomeFirstResponder];
    [self bringToFront:datePicker];
    if(date != nil){
        datePicker.date = date;
    }

    toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
    toolBar.tag = 11;
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(donePressed:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelPressed:)];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, cancelButton, nil]];
    [clientView addSubview:toolBar];
    [clientView bringSubviewToFront:toolBar];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
    toolBar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
    datePicker.frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
    backgroundView.alpha = 0.5;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

- `clientView`  is a `UIScrollView`.
 - `backgroundView` is the helper view described earlier.

This is how I add buttons. 
I wil put only a part of the button rendering code as putting all the code is unnecessary and it has lot other dependencies as well.

```
-(RenderedElement*)renderElement:(NSObject*)element:(ParentView*)parent:(PageView*)page:(Page*)modelPage:(RenderedElement*)parentRenderedElement {

    UIButton *buttonView = nil;
    Button *templateElement = nil;
    buttonView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonView setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];        
    [buttonView addTarget:parent action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [parent addSubview:buttonView];
}
```

**UPDATE**
When I change the order of rendering and if I render the buttons first the jumping effect is not happening. The UI works fine. It temporally solves the problem. But I want find the reason and have a better solution.

Comment: Are you using autolayout or structs and springs?

Comment: No I am not. Also UI is generated programmatically.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Added some of the code.

Comment: The Buttons you talk about are the UIBarButtonItem ? EDIT : After though I think it's not... can you provide code about those buttons ?

Comment: Added some of the code for button rendering. Putting all the code is not practical. Also I have lot of others pages that work well. Button rendering happen fine in those pages.

Comment: which is the parent in `renderElement`?

Comment: @sergio it parent is a UIView sub class.

Comment: I can imagine that... but you have several views: where are you adding those buttons?

Comment: @sergio Buttons and the custom UIView that contains the UIDatePicker added to the same super view. In my app each UI object(buttons, textboxes, etc) has a separate class to render the given UI object. Eg Buttons have a button renderer class. Other objects also have separate renderers. When the a xml with the information about the UI is recieved from server, Each UI element is rendered using the renderer classes.

Comment: so, is it `clientView`?

Comment: btw, I can't see where you set the frames for your buttons...

Comment: @sergio it is added to the clientView. Frames are added in the super class of the ButtonRenderer class.           if(boundConstraint != nil){
CGRect frame = CGRectMake([[boundConstraint x]intValue ], [[boundConstraint y] intValue], [[boundConstraint width] intValue], [[boundConstraint height] intValue]);
                view.frame = frame;
            }

Comment: what happens if you remove the animation: beginAnimations/commitAnimations? Does the button still get off-place? are you sure that the code to set the button frame is not executed somewhere else?

Comment: It would be helpful to see where the 3 buttons are added via renderElement. More specifically, as sergio was getting at, what are the parent for all 3 buttons. One thing you also may want to try is for all the buttons, ascend up the view hierarchy to see if it is what is expected. If one of the buttons is moving, it sounds like it is the subview to something moving.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can add

```
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
```

after

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually say which button is moving?  Kind of hard to help without some more detail.  But here are some suggestions to look at:

Rather than adding the datepicker to the bottom of the stack and then pulling it forward:

```
[clientView addSubview:datePicker];
[clientView bringSubviewToFront:datePicker];
```

Why don't you try to try adding it by:

```
[clientView insertSubview:datePicker atIndex:0];
```

Also, you are adding the toolbar, which I assume contains the offending button, after adding the datPicker and then pulling that forward.  Do you want the toolbar to be above the datepicker in the view hierachy?

Perhaps insert it at:

```
[clientView insertSubview:toolBar aboveSubview:datePicker];
```

Finally, do you need to animate the toolbar frame?

Comment: I tried ur suggestion. But it did not work. UIButton rendered in the UIView is moving. Yes tool bar frame is also animating.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can imagine is that may be you have this button on the client view. and since you are adding and moving this

```
[clientView addSubview:datePicker];
[clientView bringSubviewToFront:datePicker];
```

this may cause readjusting of your UIButton's frame. and since that happens during this procedure it also animates its movement which may appear as a jumping button..so i guess you should try

```
[jumpingButton setAnimationsEnabled:NO];  //you-know jumping button is the outlet of the -you-know-who
```